# how to update a variable in a .mat file for matlab?

Tags: matlab, save, matlab-load

I have a matlab .mat file that stores a bunch of variables.  How do I update a single variable?

I tried doing this:

```
load('filename.mat');
variable='Test';
save('filename.mat',variable);
```

but it says

```
??? Error using ==> save
Variable 'C:\' not found.
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: `load` loads all variables in the .mat file into the current workspace, so you shouldn't need to specify which variables to save should you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for the "-append" option:

```
save('filename.mat','-append');
```

From http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html

> For MAT-files, -append adds new variables to the file or replaces the
>   saved values of existing variables with values in the workspace.

Answer (score -1):

To save an individual variable to a .mat file, you need to quote its name:

```
save('filename.mat','variable');
```

See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/save.html.

Comment: doesn't this create a file with only 'variable' in it? If there are other variables in the file, they will be lost.